# Filtering by alphanumeric

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I want to sort a table by a column named 'generic_location'.
generic location data is conformed by numbers, letters and then numbers like these:
'4A1', '5AW89', '7AA89', ETC

I trying to split the data using **regexp_substr** and order by **CAST(generic_location AS UNSIGNED) ASC**  but it doesn't show as I want.
this is what I get.

- 4A14
- 4A15
- 4AW39
- 4AW70
- 4A75
- 4AW83

This is my current query:

```
SELECT gen_loc,
    regexp_substr(generic_location, '^[0-9]*') AS `A`,
    regexp_substr(generic_location, '[A-Z]+') AS `B`,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(generic_location, '([0-9]+[A-Z]+)+', '') AS `C`
FROM boms ORDER BY CAST(A AS UNSIGNED) ASC, CAST(B AS UNSIGNED), CAST(C AS UNSIGNED);
```

I want the column order shows like:

- 4A14
- 4A15
- 4A75
- 4AW39
- 4AW70
- 4AW83

Is there any way to order the generic location column like this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is casting varchar to int perhaps hoping to obtain ASCII code sum.

The correct query is the following where MySQL is using inbuilt alphabetical sorting

```
SELECT gen_loc,
    regexp_substr(generic_location, '^[0-9]*') AS `A`,
    regexp_substr(generic_location, '[A-Z]+') AS `B`,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(generic_location, '([0-9]+[A-Z]+)+', '') AS `C`
FROM boms ORDER BY CAST(A AS UNSIGNED) ASC, B, CAST(C AS UNSIGNED);
```

Notice B is not being cast.

Also, not sure why you had to use substrings, the following query achieves the same result

```
SELECT gen_loc, generic_location FROM boms ORDER BY generic_location ASC;
```

Comment: Thank You! the first query works as I want.

SELECT gen_loc, generic_location FROM boms ORDER BY generic_location ASC;
I tried this query but doesnt work as you say because start with a generic location 10A1, 10A10, etc. I dont know if could be the data type or somenthing. 

Thank you!!